# WCF Service Hosting

Tags: wcf

I host a WCF Service in IIS, but it is giving following error:-

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>
> The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

I developed this service in .Net Framework 4.0 and applied `basicHttpBinding` for SOAP.

I also tried `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` command but still my problem did not get resolved.

Http Binding is as follow:-

```
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServBehave">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the server-side and client-side configs and the code you're using to access the service

Comment: I set Http windows feature and now it's working but now issue comes of accessing data from Service.  Now I am trying to access Service using my machine ip address following by my service detail as http://MyMachineIP/wcfservice/Service1.svc/GetUserData  But It is giving 404 not found error.

Comment: Again: **show us your configs!** And also: `basicHttpBinding` is a **SOAP** binding - you cannot test a SOAP binding by just browsing to it with a browser - you'll need a SOAP-capable test tool, like the WCF Test Client or Soap UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure WCF is installed and enabled on the server.

1. Make sure that the .NET 3.5.1 Framework is installed.
2. Ensure that “Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation is enabled and installed. This can be access via the Program Features in the Control panel under “Turn Windows Features on or off”.
3. Execute below command from command prompt running as Administrator (elivated privileges ).

"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -i